# Approaching limit of the sum using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, analysis

How to approach this limit using squeeze theorem?

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k=n}^{3n}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^4+k}}}}$

I tried to use squeeze theorem. Namely, what i did was

$\sum_{k=n}^{3n}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^{4} + 3n}}} \leq\sum_{k=n}^{3n}{\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^4+k}}}\leq \sum_{k=n}^{3n}{\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^{4} + n}}}$

but it did not provide me any conclusions about the same limits from both sides. I struggle with those type of squeeze-theoroem-like limits, where both numerator and denominator has got a variable. Any hints or solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have got the right bounds for the denominator. Keep $k$ in the numerator and use that fact that $\sum_{k=a}^{b} k=\frac {b(b+1)}2-\frac {(a-1) a} 2$.

Comment: could you provide me more evaluation of this formula?

Comment: Do you know the value of $1+2+3+...+n$?

Comment: @MaciejOstapiuk additivity property, convince yourself the sum of the arithmetic sequence $1+2+\ldots + n = \binom{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: I solved it, thanks